# Vim crashes during some Ruby autocompletion but not always

Tags: ruby, macos, vim

The Background:
I have a fairly [customized vim](https://github.com/todd-dsm/vimSimple) configuration that's been working without error for years on both Linux and OS X (10.8/9). This problem is occurring on the Mac; untested on Linux. I use the latest version of vim from Homebrew and I only use it in the terminal.

The problem:
I'm learning Ruby. At some point I copy/paste some code into a file.rb script and :wq - no problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

print "Thtring, pleathe!: "
user_input = gets.chomp
user_input.downcase!

if user_input.include? "s" 
  user_input.gsub!(/s/, "th")
  user_input.capitalize!
else
  puts "Nothing to do here!"
end

puts "Your string is: #{user_input}"
```

When I go back to edit that file to add another user_input method:

1. I begin by dropping a log: vim -V9 /tmp/vim.log
2. Read-in my file: `:r file.rb`
3. Hop to line 10:   `:10`
4. Add a new line in insert mode: `o`
5. Enter: user_input (the autocompletion kicks in), select the object `user_input`
6. And when I hit `.` the session freezes.

The output looks like this:

```
[Buf: 1][+] /private/tmp/vim.log [utf-8]     [0x2E] [Line: 0011/0018 | Col: 13]   (All) 
Executing InsertEnter Auto commands for "*"                                               
autocommand unlet! s:posLast s:lastUncompletable
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Executing CursorMovedI Auto commands for "*"
Press ENTER or type command to continue
autocommand call s:feedPopup()
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Executing CursorMovedI Auto commands for "*"
Press ENTER or type command to continue
autocommand call s:Highlight_Matching_Pair()
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

The only thing I get from this is **s:lastUncompletable** - something is 'uncompletable'

I should say I've used AutoComplPop for years without error. In the last 24 hours I've also attempted with YouCompleteMe. I get the same result with both.

At the same time, in another shell with the same vim config, [this ruby test](https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby/wiki/VimRubySupport#verifying-installation) works just fine. But it does indicate there is a problem specific to ruby.

I'm just not sure where to go from here. If there are some viml experts that can lend some guidance, I'd be grateful.

TT

Comment: Is is freezing (Ctrl-C gets you out of this), or crashing? The former can be a plugin issue, the latter should be reported to the vim_dev / vim_mac mailing list.

Comment: It must be crashing then, Ctrl-C does not get me out of it. Thanks for the assist.

Comment: Did this ever get fixed? I'm having this same issue now?

Comment: Since you're having the same issue I'd say probably not. I was hoping to get some feedback from someone more knowledgeable  (here) so I could file a better bug. I should have just filed it.